# Why paint class is not working with setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)

Tags: java

```
package Jai;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class tuna extends JFrame{

    tuna(){
        super("Title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);

        g.fillOval(50, 100, 100, 155);      
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        tuna obj = new tuna();
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setSize(500,500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have a `JFrame` where I use the paint method to draw an Oval on the frame.
Whenever I try to maximize or minimize the window than the oval drawn through the `paint()` method disappears. I want the drawn graphics to stay even when I maximize or minimize the frame.

Comment: It happens because no `repaint` is called. Reasoning is probably windows not sending an event with `setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated` set to true that Swing would require to trigger the `repaint`.

Comment: You shouldn't be drawing directly on the JFrame to begin with. You should draw within a JPanel's paintComponent method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is overriding of a wrong method for a wrong object. You must override `paintComponent` method for the main panel. Here is the correct code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class tuna extends JFrame {
    tuna() {
        super("Title");
        // you need to override the method paintComponent for the main panel
        setContentPane(new JPanel(new FlowLayout()) {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.fillOval(50, 100, 100, 155);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        tuna obj = new tuna();
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setSize(500, 500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```